# Flutter Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

This is my userdata.dart

```
 class UserData{
 late String name;
 late String age;

 UserData({
   this.name = "",
   this.age = "",
 });

 factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
   return new UserData(
     name: parsedJson['Name'],
     age: parsedJson['Age'],
   );
 }
```

The provider.dart:

```
  Future getPatient(
      String uId, BuildContext context) async {
    uId = '60aa563cb2bd01aaeb5a94ac';
    http.Response user =
        await http.get(Uri.https("link.com", "getUser/$uId"));
    var userJson = jsonDecode(user.body);
    print("Patient data: ${userJson}"); /// code works till here as it prints
    UserData users = new UserData.fromJson(userJson);
    print("Patient Name ${users.name[0]}");
    return patients;
  }
}
```

User model

```
{_id: {$oid: 60aa563cb2bd01aaeb5a9sdfs}, Email: xyz@gmail.com, Name: pqr, Age: 20, Gender: Male, Phone: 23478917883}
```

I want to retrieve the data for every id (name and age of the user). When I'm trying to retrieve the data, I'm facing this error.

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'int'
```

I'm new to flutter and Stackoverflow. Can you please help me in telling what is the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: use age as int instead of string

Answer (score 1):

This error means that one of the fields that you are parsing is an `int` but you are initializing it to a variable of type `String`

In your data Age and Phone are `int`
So make the following changes in your model class

```
class UserData{
 String? name;
 int? age;     //change this to int from String

 UserData({
  @required this.name,
  @required this.age,
 });

 factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
   return new UserData(
     name: parsedJson['Name'],
     age: parsedJson['Age'],
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: I did changed it, but we can't assign `this.age = ""` as we do that for string and due to _null_ _safety_ I need to add **required** before _this.age_. But doing that gives me this error
`Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'`.

Comment: @InfiniteLearner My mistake, I completely overlooked the initialization part. Try the edited code; it should work!